# Regex to replace <br> and <br/> with \n

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to replace `<br>` or `<br/>` tags with `/n`(newline).

What is the pattern for this with regex?

Comment: @ArupRakshit: You're kidding, right? A 100 MB dependecy for a such small task?

Comment: @RokKralj No,.. I am not.. HTML/XML parsing is best done by `Nokogiri`.. May be it would come in future with Ruby stdlib part I wish

Answer (score 7):

Ruby:

`a = "I want to replace <br> or <br/> tags with /n(newline)."
puts a
a.gsub!(%r~<br\s*\/?>~, "\n")
puts a`

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could use a delimiter of your own choice when using `%r` to define a Regexp, I thought it had to be `%r{ .. }`. It seems you can use almost any character. By the way, since you do not use `/` as delimiter you do not have to escape it. `%r~/~` becomes `/\//`